# Displaying current date in notification even though specified in another in setWhen()

Tags: android, android-notifications

I creating an android notification with this code block:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ARG_KEY, nd.getIntentArgValue());
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
          .getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
      NotificationManager notifManager =
          (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      String channelId = "notifications_channel";
      int ledColor = Color.MAGENTA;
      int iconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String channelName = "messages notification channel";
        String channelDescription = "This channel is for receive critical notifications";
        int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
            new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(ledColor);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 100, 300, 200 });
        if (notifManager != null)
          notifManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
      }
      Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
          new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_notification).setContentTitle(nd.getTitle())
              .setContentText(nd.getDescription()).setAutoCancel(true).setColor(iconColor)
              .setWhen(nd.getWhen() * 1_000).setShowWhen(true).setLights(ledColor, 200, 2000)
              .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
              .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(nd.getDescription()))
              .setTicker(nd.getDescription()).setSound(defaultSoundUri)
              .setCategory(nd.getCategory())
              //.setGroup(nd.getGroup())
              .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
      if (notifManager != null) {
        FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureTarget =
            GlideApp.with(context).asBitmap().load(nd.getLargeImage()).circleCrop().submit();
        LoadImageTask task = new LoadImageTask(icon -> {
          notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);
          GlideApp.with(context).clear(futureTarget);
          notifManager.notify(nd.getTag(), nd.getId(), notificationBuilder.build());
        });
        task.execute(futureTarget);
      }
```

I used setWhen() for display specific notification date as you see.
But Android Oreo incorrectly displays the date that notification recived as 'notification date' instead of date that specified in setWhen()